# How to COUNT rows according to specific complicated rules?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, rows

I have the following table:

```
custid  custname  channelid  channel  dateViewed
--------------------------------------------------------------
1          A       1         ABSS     2016-01-09  
2          B       2         STHHG    2016-01-19 
3          C       4         XGGTS    2016-01-09 
6          D       4         XGGTS    2016-01-09 
2          B       2         STHHG    2016-01-26 
2          B       2         STHHG    2016-01-28 
1          A       3         SSJ      2016-01-28 
1          A       1         ABSS     2016-01-28 
2          B       2         STHHG    2016-02-02
2          B       7         UUJKS    2016-02-10
2          B       8         AKKDC    2016-02-10
2          B       9         GGSK     2016-02-10
2          B       9         GGSK     2016-02-11
2          B       7         UUJKS    2016-02-27
```

And I want the results to be:

```
custid  custname  month count  
------------------------------
1          A       1     1
2          B       1     1      
2          B       2     4     
3          C       1     1
6          D       1     1
```

According to the following rules:

- All channel views subscription is billed every 15 days. If the
  customer viewed the same channel within the 15 days, he will only be
  billed once for that channel. For instance, custid 2, custname B his billing cycle is 19 Jan - 3 Feb (one billing cycle), 4 Feb - 20 Feb (one billing cycle) and so on. Therefore, he is billed only 1 time in Jan since he watch the same channel throughout the billing cycle; and he is billed 4 times in Feb for watching (channelid 7, 8, 9) and channelid 7 watched on 27 Feb (since this falls in another billing cycle, customer B is also charged here). Customer B is not charged on 2 Feb for watching channel 2 since he was already billed in 19 jan - 3 Feb billing cycle.
- An invoice is generated every month for each customer, therefore, the
  results should show the 'Month' and the 'Count' of the channels
  viewed for each customer.

Can this be done in SQL server?

Comment: No data for 2015 in the table?

Comment: what's the billing cycle rules? are they on fixed dates or do they change?

Comment: It can be done, but the billing cycles need to be defined somewhere (either in code, or in a table).  Are they unique periods for each customer, or are the billing cycles the same for everyone?

Comment: @jarlh only 2016 data is taken into consideration.

Comment: @Sturgus billing cycles is fixed - every 15 days (unique periods for each customer though). For instance, cust 1, billing cycle starts on 9 Jan, cust 2, billing cycle starts on 19 Jan and so on. This billing cycle will continue every 15 days for every customer until the customer decides to stop using the service.

Comment: @ZoharPeled billing cycles is fixed to every 15 days for all customers and will not change throughout the year

Comment: @saturday then you're going to need to define that (probably in your customers table).  Your customers table might looks something like:
`CREATE TABLE Customers (
   custid int primary key,
   custname varchar(100),
   BillingCycleStart date

   --insert other relevant fields
);` And then you'll have to do math to it in a join...

Comment: @Sturgus what if I want to define it in the code? Any other alternatives besides defining it in the table? How to write a query that can be run every month to generate the monthly invoice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  custid,
            custname, 
            channelid, 
            channel, 
            dateViewed,
            CAST(DATEADD(day,15,dateViewed) as date) as dateEnd,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custid, channelid ORDER BY dateViewed) AS rn
    FROM (VALUES
        (1, 'A', 1, 'ABSS', '2016-01-09'),(2, 'B', 2, 'STHHG', '2016-01-19'),
        (3, 'C', 4, 'XGGTS', '2016-01-09'),(6, 'D', 4, 'XGGTS', '2016-01-09'),
        (2, 'B', 2, 'STHHG', '2016-01-26'),(2, 'B', 2, 'STHHG', '2016-01-28'),
        (1, 'A', 3, 'SSJ', '2016-01-28'),(1, 'A', 1, 'ABSS', '2016-01-28'),
        (2, 'B', 2, 'STHHG', '2016-02-02'),(2, 'B', 7, 'UUJKS', '2016-02-10'),
        (2, 'B', 8, 'AKKDC', '2016-02-10'),(2, 'B', 9, 'GGSK', '2016-02-10'),
        (2, 'B', 9, 'GGSK', '2016-02-11'),(2, 'B', 7, 'UUJKS', '2016-02-27')
        ) as t(custid, custname, channelid, channel, dateViewed)
), res AS (
    SELECT custid, channelid, dateViewed, dateEnd, 1 as Lev
    FROM cte
    WHERE rn = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.custid, c.channelid, c.dateViewed, c.dateEnd, lev + 1
    FROM res r
    INNER JOIN cte c ON c.dateViewed > r.dateEnd and c.custid = r.custid and c.channelid = r.channelid
), final AS (
    SELECT  * ,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custid, channelid, lev ORDER BY dateViewed) rn,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY custid, channelid, dateEnd) dr
    FROM res
)

SELECT  b.custid,
        b.custname, 
        MONTH(f.dateViewed) as [month],
        COUNT(distinct dr) as [count]
FROM cte b
LEFT JOIN final f
    ON b.channelid = f.channelid and b.custid = f.custid and b.dateViewed between f.dateViewed and f.dateEnd
WHERE f.rn = 1
GROUP BY b.custid,
        b.custname, 
        MONTH(f.dateViewed)
```

Output:

```
custid      custname month       count
----------- -------- ----------- -----------
1           A        1           3
2           B        1           1
2           B        2           4
3           C        1           1
6           D        1           1

(5 row(s) affected)
```

I don't know why you get `1` in `count` field for customer `A`. He got:

```
ABSS     2016-01-09 +1 to count (+15 days = 2016-01-24)
SSJ      2016-01-28 +1 to count
ABSS     2016-01-28 +1 to count (28-01 > 24.01)
```

So in January there must be `count = 3`.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I am trying to count things with complex criteria, I use a sum and case statement.  Something like below:

```
SELECT custid, custname, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN somecriteria
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END) As CriteriaCount
FROM whateverTable
GROUP BY custid, custname
```

You can make that `somecriteria` variable as complicated a statement as you like, so long as it returns a boolean.  If it passes, this row returns a 1.  If it fails, the row reutrns a 0, then we sum up the values returned to get the count.

Answer (score 0):

> @Sturgus what if I want to define it in the code? Any other
>   alternatives besides defining it in the table? How to write a query
>   that can be run every month to generate the monthly invoice. –
>   saturday 15 mins ago

Well, one way or another, you will have to save each customer's billing start date (minimally).  If you want to do this entirely in SQL without 'editing the database', something like the following should work.  The drawback to this approach is that you would need to manually edit the "INSERT INTO" statement every month to suit your needs.  If you were allowed to edit the already existing customers table or create a new one, then it would reduce this manual effort.

```
DECLARE @CustomerBillingPeriodsTVP AS Table(
   custID int UNIQUE,
   BillingCycleID int,
   BillingStartDate Date,
   BillingEndDate Date
);
INSERT INTO @CustomerBillingPeriodsTVP (custID, BillingCycleID, BillingStartDate, BillingEndDate) VALUES
 (1, 1, '2016-01-03', '2016-01-18'), (2, 1, '2016-01-18', '2016-02-03'), (3, 1, '2016-01-15', '2016-01-30'), (6, 1, '2016-01-14', '2016-01-29');

SELECT A.custid, A.custname, B.BillingCycleID AS [month], COUNT(DISTINCT A.channelid) AS [count]
FROM dbo.tblCustomerChannelViews AS A INNER JOIN @CustomerBillingPeriodsTVP AS B ON A.custid = B.CustID
GROUP BY A.custid, A.custname, B.BillingCycleID;
GO
```

Where are you getting your customers' billing start dates as it is?

Answer (score 0):

Generally this is how you can get any number (10 in this example) of fixed 15 day intervals starting at the given date (@dd in this example).

```
DECLARE @dd date = CAST('2016-01-19 17:30' AS DATE);

WITH E1(N) AS (
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), 
E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b),  --10,000 rows max
tally(N) AS (SELECT TOP (10) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4)
SELECT
    startd = DATEADD(D,(N-1)*15, @dd),
    endd = DATEADD(D, N*15-1, @dd)    
FROM tally
```

Adapt it to the rules defining how start date must be calculated for the user (and probably chanel).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this solution will scale - but with some good index candidates and decent data housekeeping, it'll work..

You're going to need some extra info for starters, and to normalize your data.  You will need to know the first charging period start date for each customer.  So store that in a customer table.

Here are the tables I used:

```
create table #channelViews
(
    custId int, channelId int, viewDate datetime
)
create table #channel 
(
    channelId int, channelName varchar(max)
)
create table #customer 
(
    custId int, custname varchar(max), chargingStartDate datetime
)
```

I'll populate some data.  I won't get the same results as your sample output, because I don't have the appropriate start dates for each customer.  Customer 2 will be OK though.

```
insert into #channel (channelId, channelName)
select 1, 'ABSS'
union select 2, 'STHHG'
union select 4, 'XGGTS'
union select 3, 'SSJ'
union select 7, 'UUJKS'
union select 8, 'AKKDC'
union select 9, 'GGSK'

insert into #customer (custId, custname, chargingStartDate)
select 1, 'A', '4 Jan 2016'
union select 2, 'B', '19 Jan 2016'
union select 3, 'C', '5 Jan 2016'
union select 6, 'D', '5 Jan 2016'

insert into #channelViews (custId, channelId, viewDate)
select 1,1,'2016-01-09'  
union select 2,2,'2016-01-19' 
union select 3,4,'2016-01-09' 
union select 6,4,'2016-01-09' 
union select 2,2,'2016-01-26' 
union select 2,2,'2016-01-28' 
union select 1,3,'2016-01-28' 
union select 1,1,'2016-01-28' 
union select 2,2,'2016-02-02'
union select 2,7,'2016-02-10'
union select 2,8,'2016-02-10'
union select 2,9,'2016-02-10'
union select 2,9,'2016-02-11'
union select 2,7,'2016-02-27'
```

And here is the somewhat unweildy query, in a single statement.
The two underlying sub-queries are actually the same data, so there may be more appropriate / efficient ways to generate these.

We need to exclude from billing any channel charged in the same charging period C for the previous Month.  This is the essence of the join.  I used a right-join so that I could exclude all such matches from the results (using `old.custId is null`).

```
select c.custId, c.[custname], [month], count(*) [count] from 
(
    select new.custId, new.channelId, new.month, new.chargingPeriod
    from 
        (
        select distinct cv.custId, cv.channelId, month(viewdate) [month], (convert(int, cv.viewDate) - convert(int, c.chargingStartDate))/15 chargingPeriod
        from #channelViews cv join #customer c on cv.custId = c.custId
        ) old
    right join 
        (
        select distinct cv.custId, cv.channelId, month(viewdate) [month], (convert(int, cv.viewDate) - convert(int, c.chargingStartDate))/15 chargingPeriod
        from #channelViews cv join #customer c on cv.custId = c.custId
        )  new
    on old.custId = new.custId 
        and old.channelId = new.channelId 
        and old.month = new.Month -1
        and old.chargingPeriod = new.chargingPeriod

    where old.custId is null
    group by new.custId, new.month, new.chargingPeriod, new.channelId

) filteredResults
join #customer c on c.custId = filteredResults.custId
group by c.custId, [month], c.custname
order by c.custId, [month], c.custname
```

And finally my results:

```
custId custname month count
1      A        1     3
2      B        1     1
2      B        2     4
3      C        1     1
6      D        1     1
```

This query does the same thing:

```
select c.custId, c.custname, [month], count(*) from 
(
    select cv.custId, min(month(viewdate)) [month], cv.channelId
    from #channelViews cv join #customer c on cv.custId = c.custId
    group by cv.custId, cv.channelId, (convert(int, cv.viewDate) - convert(int, c.chargingStartDate))/15
) x
join #customer c 
 on c.custId = x.custId
group by c.custId, c.custname, x.[month]
order by custId, [month]
```

Comment: What a difference a good night's sleep makes.  Have added a more manageable query that gives the same results.